# How universal is the -L (dereference symlink) switch of the 'ls' command?

Tags: scripting, ls, symlink, compatibility

I have some software that, among other things, needs to:

- Assess a file's rwxrwxrwx permissions;
- Work under every possible flavor of Unix and Linux you can find in the wild.

Currently, it does that running the `ls -l` command. If the file is a symlink, I have to get the permissions of the target file. The `-L` switch works nicely for that.

The question: Are there flavors of Unix in which I run the risk of that switch not being available? If so, which ones? (If they're rare enough and old enough, I might just be able to ignore the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's in the [GNU](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=ls), [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls), [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ls&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html), and general [BSD](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ls/) `ls` implementations, so I'd say it's pretty likely to be anywhere.

Comment: I think I remember it being in System V from 20 years ago too.

Comment: Also present on SunOS 5.7 (which is often very good at not having useful switches).

Answer (score 6):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) if you can help it.  Depending on what you're doing, the `test` utility might be a better alternative.

`test -r filename` will return success if the file is readable with the current user's permissions, and will follow symbolic links automatically.  Likewise, `-w` and `-x` will tell you if the file is writable or executable.  The `test` command is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html), and so ought to work with any modern UNIX.

If you really need to know the specific permissions of the file, `ls` might be the most portable way, as long as you only use it on one file at a time.  In that case, the `-L` and `-l` flags are also [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html), so you should be reasonably safe.  (See "[Don't Parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)" for a little more commentary on the portabilty of the output fields of `ls -l`.)

Another option might be to write a short C program to take advantage of the [`stat(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/stat.html) system call, which *will* be available on every UNIX under the sun.  If this is a small part of a larger piece of software that's already being compiled from C, this might be the best option.

Comment: i have tried the `test` program on my system and it seems that it isn't work, it doesn't output anything (even not to sterr). Archlinux

Comment: While “don't parse the output of `ls`” is good advice in general, the specific case of parsing `ls -l` on a single file when you're after the permissions or link count is safe.

Comment: @HananN. `test` doesn't produce any output unless you make a syntax error. It returns information through its exit status: 0 if the test is true, ≥1 if the test is false.

Answer (score 3):

It is in SUSv3 (Posix 2001) but not in SUSv2 (alias Unix98).